# transact-sql question

Tags: sql, t-sql

Assume there were 100 records in tableA and tableA contained a column named 'price'.

How do I select the first-n record if where sum of price > a certain amount (e.g. 1000) without using cursor?

thanks

Comment: @user384080 - 1. what database? 2. Summation of price based on what criteria?

Comment: Do you wish to sum the price grouped by another column and test it?

Comment: I think you guys all misunderstood the question sorry.. Basically I need to sum the price column and if the same has reached the limit then take the records. So if the price in record #1 + the price in record #2 + the price in record #3 has reached the limit then take those three records otherwise keep on looping thru the records until reaching the limit

Comment: @user384080: "...until reaching the limit" - then what? Return the record on which the limit was reached? Return the sum of price at the point the limit was reached? Something else? Also, how are you ordering these records, ie. what determines which record is #1, #2, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top N implies some kind of order, which you did not supply, so I assumed any random order.

You can change this on the OVER clause of the [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Try something like

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Price FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 11
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 12
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 15
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 10
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 65
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 100

DECLARE @TotalPrice FLOAT
SELECT  @TotalPrice = 100

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) RNR
        FROM    @Table
)
, Totals AS (
        SELECT  v.RNR,
                SUM(vP.Price) TotalPrice
        FROM    Vals v LEFT JOIN
                Vals vP ON  v.RNR >= vP.RNR
        GROUP BY    v.RNR
)
, LimitValue AS (
        SELECT  TOP 1 
                RNR
        FROM    Totals
        WHERE   TotalPrice >= @TotalPrice
        ORDER BY    RNR
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Vals 
WHERE   RNR <= (
                    SELECT  RNR
                    FROM    LimitValue
                )
```

Comment: typically, set based queries are faster than cursors, but you should test and benchmark this.

Comment: yes.. have tested for 41K records with average selecting 12K records, the query run for 10 minutes.. is there away to speed it up?

Comment: Do you have any indexes on the table?

Answer (score -1):

select price from tableA
where price > 1000
limit n;

n - no. of records you want in result set

--
Cheers

Comment: I think you guys all misunderstood the question sorry.. Basically I need to sum the price column and if the same has reached the limit then take the records. So if the price in record #1 + the price in record #2 + the price in record #3 has reached the limit then take those three records otherwise keep on looping thru the records until reaching the limit